# Embed a webclip

Tags: embed, widget, html

I am wondering if there's a way I can embed a webclip into a webpage, as in, I can have a portion of a webpage embedded as a widget into another page. I was thinking it might be possible someway though Mac OS X's Dashboard widgets, one can take a webclip and make a dashboard widget, as I hear that they are HTML based, and thus one could reverse-engineer one into simple HTML code. Kind of the reverse of what google does for gadgets. Any ideas? I'm open to any solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy, html-based way is with an iframe. What this does is put an entire webpage within a box on your page. You don't have much flexibility with it.

You can also do it with javascript. JQuery makes it easy with their .load() method. Going this route, you can load a webpage with javascript, load specific tags within that page, or even modify the incoming code before displaying it.

Most basically:

```
$("#xxxx").load("url.html");
```

Where xxxx is the id of the html tag where you want the content to be loaded on your page (e.g. if you have `<div id="xxxx">content will go here</div>` in your HTML). See more details at: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load.

If these don't suffice, the next step would be PHP (I doubt you'd need it, but if you'd like to, you car search for file_get_contents on php.net).